# Login Issues using bcrypt on node.js

Tags: node.js, authentication, bcrypt

folks, having issues in retrieving uname pwd for login, using bcrypt on node.js ... I am a rookie, you know, sorry if this question is not smart ... code below ...I'm not getting any error, either I enter a wrong password or correct password the code returns the line "res.status(200).send(" successfully logeed in " +username" ....

```
app.post("/users/signin", function(req, res){
var {username, password} = req.body; //deconstructing again!!! 
    User.findOne({username: username}, "username password", function(err, userBody){
        if (!err){
            var pwdcheck = bcrypt.compare(userBody.password, password); //decrypt password
            console.log("password check: inserted pwd is " + userBody.password + " retreived is " + password);
            if (pwdcheck) {
                console.log("pwdcheck returns " + pwdcheck);
                req.session.user = {
                   username: userBody.username,
                   password: userBody.password
                };
                req.session.user.expires = new Date( //giving a session duration for the user
                    Date.now() + 24 * 3600 * 60 * 1000
               );
               res.status(200).send(" successfully logeed in " +username );        
           } else {
           res.status(401).send(" invalid credentials 1 " +username );
           }
    } else {
        res.status(401).send(" invalid credentials 2 " +username );
        }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `bcrypt.compare` is an asynchronous function.  When you assign the variable, you are not assigning the return value of the function, but the function itself.  Since the function is not `null`, your `if` statement intended to test the return value will always evaluate to `true`.  Try using `bcrypt.compareSync` instead.

Also, you might have the plaintext and hashed passwords reversed.  The plaintext password from the request should be the first argument and the hashed password from the stored user record should be the second: `bcrypt.compareSync(plaintext, hash)`.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt